# Django forms for sex

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am working with a database that stores sex as 0 - male and 1 - female.

My forms.py looks like this

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = TbUser

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            TbUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except TbUser.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])


class TbUserRegisterForm(CustomUserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = TbUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'cellphone', 'sex', 'role', 'department', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Django user model

```
class TbUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32, default=uuid.uuid4)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, unique=True, db_column='usname')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, db_column='dj_psword')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    cellphone = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    image_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    sex = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_available = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.ForeignKey(TbRole, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.ForeignKey(TbDepartment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True, db_column='default_super')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = TbUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tb_user'

    
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.username
```

Since sex is an integer field, the UI form field is not a choice field but just showing arrows for incrementing the integer. Is there a way to make it a choice field that for m will store 0 and f - 1?

[image: This is how it works now]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can assign this to the [**`choices=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices):

```
SEX_CHOICES = [
    (0, 'Male')
  , (1, 'Female')
]

class TbUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # …
    sex = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, choices=SEX_CHOICES)
    # …
```